# Minimal example of Task Scheduler Blink?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

[Scheduler_example00_Blink](https://github.com/arkhipenko/TaskScheduler/tree/master/examples/Scheduler_example00_Blink) is ~300 lines. For just an Arduino Uno, what is a minimal example?

It's hard to know what belongs and what doesn't. This example has six different approaches, and I'm just trying to extract one of them.

Comment: what about the scheduler template?

Comment: the main GitHub page for the library has a link to an awesome web based Arduino emulator .... https://wokwi.com/playground/task-scheduler ... try deleting sections of code until you are left with minimum

Comment: i don't see it as being personal ... i am glad that you were able to work through it ... learning experience ... please don't forget to accept your own answer

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <TaskScheduler.h>

// Scheduler
Scheduler ts;

/*
   Approach 1: LED is driven by the boolean variable; false = OFF, true = ON
*/
#define PERIOD1 500
#define DURATION 10000
void blink1CB(); // <-------------------------------------------|
Task tBlink1 ( PERIOD1 * TASK_MILLISECOND, DURATION / PERIOD1, &blink1CB, &ts        , true );
//           (     500 * 1UL (ms)        , 100000 ms/ 500    , function , just put it,  ?   )



void setup()
{
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  ts.execute();
}




inline void LEDOn() {
  digitalWrite( LED_BUILTIN, HIGH );
}

inline void LEDOff() {
  digitalWrite( LED_BUILTIN, LOW );
}



// === 1 =======================================
bool LED_state = false;
void blink1CB()
{
  if ( LED_state )
  {
    LEDOff();
    LED_state = false;
  }
  else
  {
    LEDOn();
    LED_state = true;
  }
}
```